# Returning difference between two strings (irrespective of their type)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

We have a data frame and need to compare two its columns.

`Column 1 (Name: PN) = 555, 333, 444`

`Column 2 (Name: whatever)= "555A", 333, "444B"`

**We need to get the difference, i.e. "A" and "B"**. Neither of variants found in the net worked in my try.
These are columns, thus a series. Thus Split method doesn't apply.
Replace method does work, but doesn't return the required difference.
The diff also returns something very thoughtful, but not the required difference.

Is there a general solution, for all kinds of data (numbers, strings, ect )? Thank you.

Comment: Always, use related tags like what language your using, framework, module ect.

Comment: Can you please define the "difference" between two strings?  Some people like to use the definition of _the remainder of the second string, starting from the first position at which it is different from the first_.  But you haven't specified.  Some sample cases I'd like to know the result for:  ("", "") ("A", "") ("", "A") ("A", "B") ("AA", "A") ("A", "AA") ("AA", "ABA") ("ABBB", "BBB") ("ABC", "ABC") ("ABC", "abc").  How about I stop guessing and you just tell us your definition of _difference_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use loops, check if a character is not present in the string and you can save the difference in a variable.

Here's a way to do it in python:

```
x = 'abcd'
y = 'cdefg'

s = ''
t = ''

for i in x: # checking x with y
    if i not in y:
        s += i

for i in y: # checking y with x
    if i not in x:
        t += i

print(s)  # ab
print(t)  # efg
```

Edit:

I guess you are working in pandas column, so here's the code that would help you:

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'PN':[555, 444, 333, 222, 111],
                   'whatever':['555A', 444, '333B', 222, '111C'],})
  
A=list(df['PN']) # Coverting Column to a list
B=list(df['whatever']) # Coverting Column to a list

def convert_str(a): # Function to convert element of list to string
    return str(a)

C=[convert_str(i) for i in A] # Converting Element in List A to string
D=[convert_str(i) for i in B] # Converting Element in List B to string
E="".join(C) # Joinning the list C
F="".join(D) # Joinning the list D

diffrence=[i for i in F if i not in E] # Differences of F-E
print(diffrence) 

# Output ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: thank You. the problem is, the value in the Series are integers. Ideally, I need a list of difference between the columns. If I simply write an empty list, then a statement "if not", I get a list of the second Series, since each of its elements differs from elements of the first one. If I convert each element in a string, I get a list with singe vale which seems to be a difference between headings. Thus with single strings the "if not" works, but what works with Series?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `Series`.

Comment: a column of values. For example, I want to compare a column (starting with heading): PN, 555, 444, 333 with a column (again with heading): whatever, 555A, 444, 333B. Thus, df["PN"] and df["whatever"] are Series. If I convert both Series to lists, and make same "not in", I get a list of all variating value, thus [555A, 333B]. Thus, I still can't extract the difference itself, i.e. A and B. No change, if I convert the lists taken from the Series to strings.

Comment: are you working with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a diff function with [Longest Common Substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

[Here is my old function for getting differences between strings (TypeScript)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHYHNoF4oG8CwAoKQqUSALigCIBBAERoEkAVegeQDkKoAfSmgUQAyfZu048KfBiI4BufESgBLJABMIAD3JIArgFsARhABOcgkTBGIAN0UB7bQGdyD4EeUpTCgMbajlpMDOru6mAL6m+ABm2khewHZIUAA2Xg4AFA4AjEFuqAA0UA4ATDnuAJTY8kRetkguUAh+UJhUfgggAHSRRra6aVjJEKjAcM5FHUlDKCNQANRQmVChBWkV6AB8UK1G7RmZE1Mz85llXYpJSWkAtCdlEWaEkbZGUGmTwFAAVs1QAAwyXygAB5MFkDsM4ADPrNZhVGkYANq-AC6CM+yJ+-yqj2er3eSkxAMUwNB40mEKJMLhfgRilRKMJ+Gxgw+5MZDxZUBqSXZCnxPQA7uzmU8Xm8IB9iZhMkSSYUyYdIUoqZUOQpRXiJYDpVC5WDydMldDYaqFGaiIpIq8smioFcFhj0E75bS7Q7qYi6WjHQ0acT7ZlUd8A8iAIRzBaec1miBJBzQeG0oM+rFq6PM6NKK1pRNe9HhzbkioI8kFbkFQU+hG55OhgqfAp0qPm0LM1t4ZmW16hotQSzAXyJCgUZtQZn8iAOH7D0fMgVwc7QHM0ysI7lhqCbX4VNKWKegzJr2w8kMRvcV2wCq5XMvH693Jkc-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-tR4HvrBxQIahmG4cehH5iRiEUcBtGQZ+lEsZxvG1wJxrmOSknZPS7iKep2n6aMRmzqgFnRwUdsvcfbxuo+LxEFQScqKSxDg9I332f2UU+AQQPtIQAymvc808o+fRfKKJMxee4cxPms0MIQGzuB4fQbLKTq06DtAWrARw4H6avNpIUCGkx5bVor42u-sih+CEaROHIEve+RoEoB75EsbFyhaCkVgOFxyhJCYJeKDyFvMyGjRR4RQMt5yzaLGsOxHH3lEj7ZtPfH8aDp+vm-QlZogX8LojEkDpC33wdt8DyseCAHQboQEaKse4gDJgTFsCgNIf5IgAQAAYAFY0EFAAMxYIKAAFjwUggoqC0FUEwdgqAeCcEACEkHtRkEAA).

Press run and you will see that it correctly identifies that A and B were added :)

This is the "general" solution. If you could provide more context there could be a more efficient method.